# What GPU specs match mini PCIe x0.5

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

I'm new to computer hardware, and I'm trying to add a GPU to my computer. My computer has built in AMD support, but I need a NVIDIA GPU to support CUDA. I'm crunching numbers in a Tensorflow program.

So, [here's](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/desktops/hp-pavilion-desktop---550-a114-(energy-star)) the specs for my basic computer

Under expansion slots it has `1 mini PCIe x0.5`

So does that mean? Would it support something like [this?](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814500368R)

Is it PCIe 3.0? 2.0? x16?

What does the x16 even mean?

Comment: The x0.5 (which is just wrong, there’s no such thing as half a lane) probably refers to the fact that it’s a halt-length slot. But it doesn’t matter. There’s no graphics solution for that slot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

x16 and so on isthe number of channels. It should not normally be less than 1.  You typically cannot 'easily' put a video card into a mini PCIe slot - there's boards that break out mini pcie to a full pcie connector with its own power supply ([this google search should get you started)](https://www.google.com.sg/#q=mini+pcie+pcie+gpu&gws_rd=cr), but your mini PCIe connection would be a bottleneck even if it was 1x for more powerful cards.

x16 is the 'ideal' for a video card. x8 is what you'd use in SLI.

mini pcie is *typically* x1, so I have no idea what they mean by x0.5, unless it somehow shares a bus with something else.

I'd add, that's not a very good choice for expansion  - it looks like someone shoved laptop components into what looks like a desktop case. This could be so they could use cheap and cheerful laptop processors and such with cheap and cheerful desktop storage.  Alternatively this *might* have involved copious amounts of illegal substances, since they built a system with the expandability of a laptop and the size of a desktop. Not a good combination, since you need to suffer through the disadvantages of both.

Answer (score 0):

> So does that mean? Would it support something like the [ZOTAC GeForce
>   GT 730](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814500368R)?

Out of the box the card you mention will not be compatible.  There are passive adapters that you can purchase which would be required to make it work with the [HP Pavilion Desktop - 550-a114](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/desktops/hp-pavilion-desktop---550-a114-(energy-star)).  The Wikipedia article on [PCI Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) explains the differences between Mini PCI-E and PCI-E.  This would also apply to any PCI-E card on the market not just the one your asking about.  I should add the performance of pretty much any high performance PCI-E card placed in this system would be **absolutely abysmal** because of the bandwidth restrictions place upon it.

> due to different dimensions, PCI Express Mini Cards are not physically
>   compatible with standard full-size PCI Express slots; however, passive
>   adapters exist that allow them to be used in full-size slots

Source: [PCI Express Mini Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_Mini_Card)

> Is it PCIe 3.0? 2.0? x16?

It is none of the above.  PCI-E 3.0 indicates the revision version.  While the `x1`, `x4`, `x8`, and `x16` indicate the throughput of the PCI-E slot itself.  Each revision of PCI-E has difference capabilities.

Some related information: [History and revisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#History_and_revisions)

> So does that mean?

It means it has a PCI-Express Mini slot which is a replacement fort the mini-PCI form factor.  The `x0.5` indicate is is half the throughput of a `x1`Mini PCI-E slot.

Comment: While I feel Journeyman's answer is very good I still felt it was missing some information so I submitted my own answer.  I attempted to avoid covering what his answer said except when absolutely necessary.